# Como deixar uma transação JPA com Spring aberta?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

Gostaria de saber como deixar uma transação JPA com spring aberta, hoje eu utilizo a anotação `@Transaction` o que ocorre é que toda vez que eu quero carregar algum atributo que não está como `EAGER` gera `NullPointerException`, a solução que eu tinha antigamente era deixar a transação aberta, assim onde eu precisa-se do objeto que ainda estava `NULL`, quando eu dava um `get` nesse objeto ele buscava para mim sem problemas.
Caso não saibam como trabalhar com transações abertas, alguém tem uma solução para mim de como usar `LAZY load` com `Spring MVC` e deixar que ele gerencie minhas transações quando eu precisar delas?

> Meu método no DAO:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public Locador buscarElemento(int id) throws IdentificadorNaoExisteNaBaseDeDadosException {
            try {
                Locador locador = manager.find(Locador.class, id);
   /*
   *  Retirando os comentarios abaixo funciona, mas não é uma boa pratica,
   *  por que vai ter o mesmo comportamente do EAGER.
   */

    //          locador.getContatos().forEach(contato -> contato.getEmail());
    //          locador.getDocumentos().getCpf();
    //          locador.getEnderecos().forEach(endereco -> endereco.getBairro());*
                return locador;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new IdentificadorNaoExisteNaBaseDeDadosException(e);
            }
        }
```

> A exception gerada quando tento recuperar todos os atributos do objeto :

```
Hibernate: select locador0_.id as id1_3_0_, locador0_.codigo as codigo2_3_0_, locador0_.dataNascimento as dataNasc3_3_0_, locador0_.documentos_id as document6_3_0_, locador0_.nome as nome4_3_0_, locador0_.observacao as observac5_3_0_ from Locador locador0_ where locador0_.id=?
    abr 30, 2019 6:38:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/SistemaGestaoImobiliario] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
        at org.hibernate.Hibernate.getClass(Hibernate.java:111)
        at adapters.HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.write(HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.java:49)
        at adapters.HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.write(HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.java:19)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
        at services.GoogleJSONService.gerarJSON(GoogleJSONService.java:14)
        at control.LocadorController.carregarLocador(LocadorController.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Um título todo em maiúsculo é um pecado estilístico. Parece que está tentando chamar a atenção no grito, e não no conteúdo

Comment: Aproveitando, o que é `EAGUE`?

Comment: Coloque aqui o seu código e também a stack do erro. Procure formular bem a sua pergunta, inserindo os códigos e facilitando a vida de quem está aqui disposto a te ajudar.

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante ja editei o post, ve se consegue me ajudar por favor ! ate mais !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução para o meu problema, faltava uma propriedade a ser configurada.

> Meu arquivo de configuração do JPA

```
package config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"exceptions", "dao"})
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean manager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        // mapeia o provedor
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        // configura o data source, configurações sobre o banco de dados
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("123456");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imobiliaria?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        // propriedades do jpa
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
//      props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");

        manager.setPackagesToScan("model");
        manager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        manager.setJpaProperties(props);
        manager.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return manager;

    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        return manager;
    }

}
```

> No meu JPAConfig eu estava esquecendo da propriedade :

```
props.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
```

Assim o Hibernate abre a conexão automaticamente sempre que ele precisar buscar um objeto Lazy Load.

Até mais !!